# Hive Warehouse path uses - default path rather my own hdfs path

Tags: hadoop, hive

The problem related to Apache Hive 1.1.0 and .hiverc

I have installed apache hive 1.1.0.
By default hive hdfs home : /user/hive/warehouse,
                hdfs temp  : /tmp

I have users on the unix machine hdpadmin, hiveuser
Now i have my application specific HDFS paths

Probelm: Database is being created in the default warehouse directory rather than app specific directory : /app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE

What is the Solution for this?

```
[root@cdh1 ~]# su - hiveuser
[hiveuser@cdh1 ~]$ vim .hiverc [created a hiverc file]
SET hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE;
SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/app/myApp/HIVE/TMP;
save and close
[hiveuser@cdh1 ~]$ hive

[hiveuser@cdh1 ~]$ hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.4.5.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
WARNING: Hive CLI is deprecated and migration to Beeline is recommended.
hive> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;
hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE
hive> set hive.exec.scratchdir;
hive.exec.scratchdir=/app/myApp/HIVE/TMP
hive> create database temp;
OK
Time taken: 0.561 seconds
hive> dfs -ls /app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE;  ['temp' database not shown]
hive> desc database temp; [probelm: Creating in the default warehouse path rather my path : /app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE] 
OK
temp hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/temp.db hiveuser   USER    
Time taken: 0.217 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained on Apache Hive [Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties):

**hive.exec.scratchdir**

> Scratch space for Hive jobs. This directory is used by Hive to store the plans for different map/reduce stages for the query as well as to stored the intermediate outputs of these stages.

**hive.metastore.warehouse.dir**

> Location of default database for the warehouse.

The above explanations essentially mean that changing your scratch directory location won't help you with the database location, since this is just a temporary location used by Hive to store MapReduce job progress/plans, and any other intermediate data.

So, instead of changing the scratch directory, you can use location argument or by changing hive warehouse directory. In your case, please use this:

```
CREATE DATABASE temp LOCATION '/app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE';
```

OR

```
set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir='/app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE';
CREATE DATABASE temp;
```

You can use the former when you have varying locations for databases to be created, while the latter should be used when all the databases being created will point to the same location.

P.S. You can also make your scratch directory point to the same location as your database; but it doesn't make sense using the same location for scratch and database, unless you have a specific use-case that requires it this way, as Hive would create a lot of directories based on users executing the queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Iam able to create the temp DB in /app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE, even i wanted `hive exec scratch directory also in /app/myApp/HIVE/TMP` .hiverc has SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/app/myApp/HIVE/TMP;, but i dont see logs are not there

Comment: But in our work location we dont give like location path while creating DB. but using .hiverc path it creates automatically SET `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=/app/myApp/HIVE/WAREHOUSE;
SET hive.exec.scratchdir=/app/myApp/HIVE/TMP;`, how do we like that

Comment: Do you use beeline or hive cli ?

Comment: @NarayanaBasetty I have edited my answer. Do let me know if this suffices your requirement.

Comment: Hello Sir, i have kept the same in `.hiverc`  `/home/hiveuser/.hiverc`file but the database creates in default path., when we login to $ hive , this .hiverc file loads and sets the warehouse path, did u try with .hiverc file??, please test with my approach

Comment: the reason being is i cant set every time warehouse directory in the hive> set  hive.metastore.warehouse.dir='/some/path'; i know my warehouse, scratch paths that are set in .hiverc and i can feel free to create many databases as i wish. hope you are getting my problem statement very clearly., setting in .hiverc is a single time activity using for multuple times for multiple databases; `hive>  hive.metastore.warehouse.dir; `clearly displays my path for warehouse, please check once by replicating my statament from the original request

Comment: @NarayanaBasetty I really didn't understand what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In hive when a database is created, its information along with the default location is stored in the Hive Metastore DB (tbl:DBS and field:DB_LOCATION_URI). Hence changing Hive warehouse path property in hive configurations will not make any impact. Two ways to solve this issue (assuming you have already updated hive configurations and restarted metastore) -

- Recreate Database or use a new database.
- Update above mentioned table for desired hive database.